# Posting on wall with Mp3 Attachment using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

im trying to post to the wall of facebook with mp3 attachment doing the following:

```
      var attachment = new JsonObject();
        attachment.Add("message");
        attachment.Add("name", "Core4");
        attachment.Add("href", "www.google.com");
        attachment.Add("description", description);

        var media = new JsonObject();
        media.Add("type", "mp3");
        media.Add("src", "http://www.somesite.com/Ride.mp3");
        media.Add("href", "http://www.google.com");
        var mediaArray = new JsonArray();
        mediaArray.Add(media);
        attachment.Add("media", mediaArray);

        var result = _fbClient.Post("/me/feed", attachment);
```

post get posted but the mp3 player doesnt show! i tried everything, any one have any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Could you please post a link to an example Facebook post that does have an MP3 link in a flash player?  I've never seen that on Facebook and am always willing to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works....

```
var attachment = new JsonObject();
var media = new[]{
    new{
        type="mp3",
        src = filePath,
        title= "title", 
        artist= "art", 
        album= "album"
    }
};
//var mediaArray = new JsonArray { media };
attachment.Add("name", "sfs");
attachment.Add("href", "http://www.google.com");
attachment.Add("caption", " asdas");
attachment.Add("description", description);
attachment.Add("target_id", "1231231");
attachment.Add("media", media);

var sb = new StringBuilder("https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish?");
sb.Append("message="); sb.Append(description + "&");
sb.Append("attachment=");
sb.Append(attachment);
sb.Append("&access_token=");
sb.Append(accessToken);
var req = WebRequest.Create(sb.ToString());
req.GetResponse();
```